# VBA Excel, Compile Error, Worksheet_Change

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to put VBA code that makes it so that when I automatically input values into a table they are automatically sorted. The first piece of code works for the first table but when I try to apply it to another table it gives me this error: Compile Error: Ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_Change.

I already tried to change the name [photo of code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mScdD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You declared the same method (`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)`) twice. That's why you get the error. Which one must be run when you make changes to the worksheet? That's the ambiguity.

Add part the second's table code on to the first.

```vba
Set SalesTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2PREMARGIN")
.
.
.
End If
```

Then delete the second method.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am no longer getting the error message but the other table is still not sorting. This is the part that i cahnged:   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim SalesTable As ListObject
Dim SortCol As Range
Set SalesTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ROETABLE")
Set SalesTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2PREMARGIN")

Comment: @Seb Your second table not sorting is another issue! However, your code must first sort the first table, then when it is completed, sort the second. The code related to the second table must come AFTER the first table's code as you are using the same variables.

Comment: @Seb If your question has been successfully answered, please mark the answer as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).